# How does the coffee-script module work?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Out of curiosity how does the coffee-script module handle require 'xxx'?
It must be compiling the required file before node can load it... Does it have a specific handling for the 'require' function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that's all handled right here:

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/src/extensions.coffee

Which takes advantage of node's ability to [register extensions that runs a callback when loaded.](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions) This is now deprecated, it seems, but the functionality is still present and working.

It does other stuff too, including some gnarly monkeypatching, but here's the most relevant snippet:

```
# Load and run a CoffeeScript file for Node, stripping any `BOM`s.
loadFile = (module, filename) ->
  answer = CoffeeScript._compileFile filename, false
  module._compile answer, filename

# If the installed version of Node supports `require.extensions`, register
# CoffeeScript as an extension.
if require.extensions
  for ext in CoffeeScript.FILE_EXTENSIONS
    require.extensions[ext] = loadFile
```

Comment: It's worth noting, however, that this functionality is deprecated in Node. For details, see: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions

Comment: So how is that `loadFile` function used?  It does not change the translation of a `yyy = require xxx` line.  That is changed just enough to make it valid Javascript that node.js can use.  Normally `xxx` is Javascript, whether written from scratch or compiled from Coffeescript.

Comment: @hpaulj That callback runs when node requires a file of a specific extension. It does this: `answer = CoffeeScript._compileFile filename, false` which would return javascript.  Node can execute it then.

Answer (score 0):

So if I have a `coffee` file with the line

```
x = require './ls.coffee'
```

and run it directly with coffee, e.g. `coffee foo.coffee`, `ls.coffee` is loaded with the coffee extension (compiled and run).

But if I compile that script `coffee -c foo.coffee`, and run it with node, `node foo.js`, I get an error.  Node no longer has the `require` extension set, and all it sees is the Coffeescript code.